# Eu não consigo instalar packages porque meu pip está desatualizado e meu PyCharm não tem permissões o suficientes para realizar o upgrade

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

Estava tentando instalar o *core* porém quando digitei o seguinte comando `pip install core` me deparei com o seguinte erro

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement core (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for core
```

Eu tentei instalar o core pelas configurações de interpretadores do projeto, mas aconteceu o mesmo.
Então li que eu precisava atualizar meu Pip e digitei o seguinte código  `pip install --upgrade pip` e consequentemente apareceu este erro em meu terminal:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\rafael\pycharmprojects\iagamerproject\venv\lib\site-packages (21.1.2)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6 MB 1.1 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-21.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.1.2
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado: 'C:\\Users\\rafael\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-3z9so64q\\pip.exe'
Check the permissions.
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente mudar a execução de scripts na sua máquina:

- Abra o Windows PowerShell como administrador
- Use o comando Get-ExecutionPolicy para ver qual sua política de execução atual
- Use o Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted. (LEIA OS AVISOS DA MICROSOFT SOBRE SCRIPTS MALICIOSOS)

Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre políticas de execução aqui:
[Políticas de Execução PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score -2):

Olá!

tente reinstalar a versão do Python para pelo menos uma abaixo daqui você usando. No meu caso resolveu. Após isso feito você tenta instalar novamente os arquivos via pip install.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).